# Is there a way to set character align in the preamble

Tags: align

What I want to know is if there is some sort of preamble declaration that allows me to set a character that the `align` environment aligns on rather than having to constantly throw in the ampersand.

Like if I'm listing equations can I set in the preamble to align everything based on the equals sign?

Comment: not by default, you would have to redefine internal code, (probably not recommended)

Comment: It is worth noting that the alignment character does not get printed.  So, what you are asking is not only to change the alignment character, but to also print it.

Comment: The ampersand *is* useful to clearly see the alignment point; what if in a line you want to have two equals signs?

Answer (score 6):

It's probably not a good idea, and it's bound to break something but you can do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oldequals}{\mathrel}{operators}{`=}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a + b &= x\\
a + b + c &= x + y\\
c &= y
\end{align}


\catcode`\=\active
\def={&\oldequals}

\begin{align}
a + b = x\\
a + b + c = x + y\\
c = y
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This shouldn't be taken too seriously, but here's a “general solution”; I don't know how robust it is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defaultalignmentchars}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_ben_align_chars_seq { , } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\notalignment}{m}
 {
  \use:c { __ben_saved_#1 }
 }
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{alignatchars}{ o }
 {
  \IfValueTF{#1}
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__ben_align_chars_seq { , } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l__ben_align_chars_seq \g_ben_align_chars_seq
   }
  \ben_setup_alignment_chars:
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredfalse\m@ne
 }
 {\endalign}
\makeatother

\seq_new:N \g_ben_align_chars_seq
\seq_new:N \l__ben_align_chars_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ben_setup_alignment_chars:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ben_align_chars_seq { \ben_setup_char:N ##1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ben_setup_char:N #1
 {
  \token_if_mathchardef:NTF #1
   {
    \__ben_setup_cs:N #1
   }
   {
    \__ben_setup_ch:N #1
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ben_setup_cs:N #1
 {
  \cs_set:cpx { __ben_saved_ \cs_to_str:N #1 } { \mathchar\int_eval:n { #1 } \scan_stop: }
  \cs_set:Npn #1 { & \use:c { __ben_saved_ \cs_to_str:N #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ben_setup_ch:N #1
 {
  \cs_set:cpx { __ben_saved_ #1 } { \mathchar\char_value_mathcode:n { `#1 } \scan_stop: }
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `#1 } { 32768 } % "8000
  \__ben_redefine_ch:N #1
 }

\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^@
\cs_new:Npn \__ben_redefine_ch:N #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_lccode:nn { `^^@ } { `#1 }
  \tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end: \cs_set:Npn ^^@ } { & \use:c { __ben_saved_ #1 } }
 }
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defaultalignmentchars{=,\le}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a + b &= x = t\\
a + b + c &= x + y\\
c &\le y \le z
\end{align}

\begin{alignatchars}
a + b = x \notalignment{=} t\\
a + b + c = x + y\\
c \le y \notalignment{le} z
\end{alignatchars}

\begin{alignatchars}[\le]
a + b = x\\
a + b + c = x + y\\
c \le y \notalignment{le} z
\end{alignatchars}



\end{document}
```

The `alignatchars` environment without an optional argument uses as alignment points the characters or control sequences declared with `\defaultalignmentchars`, which accepts a comma separated list of characters and control sequences (that should be simple math characters such as `\le` or `\rightarrow`). If an optional argument is given, it should be a similar list and only those locally declared characters or control sequences will be used for alignment.

If a declared symbol shouldn't be used for alignment, it can be used as argument to `\notalignment` (without the backslash), as in the examples.

[image]

This said, it's a nice exercise, but nothing that I would really recommend using. The `&` in the input *is* good for seeing where alignment is desired.