# Align equations in cases around the equal sign

Tags: cases

So I'm trying to do a simple thing with cases:

```
$
\begin{cases}
-x+5y&=6\\
x-3y&=-4\\
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases}
-x+5y&=6\\
x&=3y-4\\
\end{cases}
$
```

And of course, LaTeX doesn't do what it should. For some reason, the "x" is far to the left.

[image]

How to make it look centered around the equal sign?

Comment: The alignment point in `cases` is for the “conditions”, not for aligning equals signs.

Comment: .... So how do I write the system of equations like people do?!

Comment: 'LaTeX doesn't do what it should' --- It did what your code told it to do. Also you don't have to dig through a mountain of websites. Try starting with the [Not So Short Guide](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/?lang=en) and the [Short Math Guide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/short-math-guide).

Comment: I dug through the first one years ago. My point is that it's not intuitive, unlike regular word processors.

Comment: It's intuitive once you get to grips with it. It's like a programming language: it does what you tell it to.

Comment: For future readers: People coming across this question looking for ways to write `=` instead of `&=` on every line of `align` environment might want to read [Is there a way to set character align in the preamble - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155105/is-there-a-way-to-set-character-align-in-the-preamble) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `cases` environment is ***not*** meant for systems of equations as the name itself hints.

You want a proper alignment environment, most likely `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  -x+5y&=6\\
  x-3y&=-4\\
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\\
&\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  -x+5y&=6\\
  x&=3y-4\\
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, okay, that works, Cases automatically added the curly brackets, so I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. One more problem, now the whole thing is in the center of the page, previously it was to the left of the oage like I wanted.

Comment: Also, what about the columns? What if I'd like to insert second system of equations next to it?

Answer (score 1):

For the first ‘cases’, thez `systeme` package yields a nicer layout (and a simpler code). For the second “cases’, you can use the `aligned` environment inside cases:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent$
\systeme{-x+5y=6, x-3y=-4}
\\[1ex]
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
-x+5y & =6,\\ x & =3y-4
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, cool, aligned inside cases. That simplifies things. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget that `cases` adds unwanted space on the right.